# How to add a character when saving files with lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have the following list

```
  L = list.files(".", ".txt")
```

which is

```
   a.txt
   b.txt
   c.txt
```

and I want to apply some code to all files in that list, but I want to save the dataframes with the samename plus some character to indicate that it is modified. For example

```
   a_modified.txt
   b_modified.txt
   c_modified.txt
```

I'm currently used this code:

```
   datalist = lapply(L, function(x) {
   DF = read.csv(x, sep = ",")
   DF$X = gsub("[:.:][[:digit:]]{1,3}","", DF$X))
   colnames(DF)[colnames(DF)=="X"] <- "ID"
   DF <- merge(DF, genes ,by="ID")
   write.csv(DF, x)
   return(DF)
   })
```

I tried using

```
   write.csv(DF, x+"_modified")
```

which was obviously wrong, as write.csv does not accept this exact operation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `paste` instead of `+`

```
write.csv(DF, paste0(sub("\\.txt", "", x), "_modified.csv"))
```

or this can be done within `sub` itself

```
write.csv(DF, sub("\\.txt", "_modified.csv", x))
```

NOTE: intial datasets were `.txt`